# Error regarding CSV table referencing column positions and number of columns

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I searched this and found posts saying that this error relates to having the wrong kind of data in a column but my data is the same as what it was previously, and also, I tried to find wrong types of data but I can't see any wrong type of data in any column. I can't even run a sample query inside Bigquery from this table without getting this error:

> Error while reading table: tester-253410.test1.TGT_22, error message: CSV table references column position 3, but line starting at position:30 contains only 2 columns.

It's a CSV file that gets uploaded into Google Cloud Storage and then queried by Bigquery. I'm trying to figure out where these positions are so that I can look at the source data and see what the possible problem might be but I don't know where position 3 is, or where line starting at position:30 is.

Comment: Please try to use autodetect schema option while loading the data !

Comment: Okay. I did this but it seems like excel saved the csv file with semicolon separators instead of comma. Some of my data has comma's in them like **0,55549675**. Maybe this is causing the problem?

Comment: use `save as` the excel file as tab delimited .txt file

Comment: Position 3 is the column number, position 30 is the number of characters into the file you are loading where the line with the problem exists. Based on your previous comment likely that Position 30 is the first row of data after the header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently replaced Office and the new Excel settings were set to use a comma as a decimal instead of a dot.
Having a comma in the data caused CSV to save with semicolons and also changed the 4 columns into 2.
Changing the comma back to a dot did the trick.